# Nestjs swagger array of strings with one parameter

Tags: swagger, nestjs, swagger-ui

When I send only one parameter, I got query result like string, not like string[]. This heppend only from UI swagger, if I send from Postman - it works good.

I just want send from swagger-ui one parammeter and got array of string, not string

How I can fix it? Help me please.

Example1: [send one paramenter and in my controller I got string like '25'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mw8Ol.png)

Example2: [when I send 2 parameters in controller I can see array of strings ('25', '21')](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JfhmO.png)

```
export class List {
  @ApiProperty({ isArray: true, type: String, required: false })
  @IsOptional()
  public categories?: string[];
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using the type like this `@ApiProperty({ type: [String] })`?

Comment: @Farista Latuconsina I just tried, but got the same result. 

`@ApiProperty({ type: [String] })`
`@ApiProperty({ type: () => [String] })`
`@ApiProperty({ type: () => [String], isArray: true })`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

when you fill a single category the query param will be translated as a string while when you fill in several categories understand it as a array.

**to solve this problem I added in DTO :**

`@Transform(({ value }) => (Array.isArray(value) ? value : Array(value)))`

I force the cast to array

Comment: As I understood swagger library can't fix that, so your answer good for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You should try to spread your parameter in a const in services
edit:

I don't know how to explain in formal words, but a array of strings of one item, for JAVASCRIPT, seems with the same thing as one string value.

Because array is not a type, but a form of a type....

So, if you, in your controller, before do anything with it, you redeclare as:

```
    @Get(":id")
    findManybyId(@Param("id") id: string[]) {
        const idArray = [...id];
        return await this.service.findManyById(idArray);
    }
```

It will solve your problem about being an array

---

old answer:

You should try to change in your controller where you make your input decorator.

in your case, i don't know if you are using ID to get, but you must to do as the example:

```
   @ApiOperation({
       summary: "Get many categories by ID",
   })
   async getMany(
       @Param("id") ids: string[],
   ) {
       return await this.categoriesService.getMany(id);
   }
```

Comment: can you write an example or explain more please?

Comment: I don't want write some logic in controller. Thanks

Comment: If you do [,,,id] where id is a string and not an array  (E.g. "hello"),  you'll get the value of the string split (["h","e","l","l","o"])